# Optimizing audio watermarking function in python

Tags: python, audio

The function takes too long to process long files (about 20 minuts soundtrack long), I need to reduce that as much as possible

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
from typing import List
from fastapi import HTTPException

OUTPUT_AUDIO_FOLDER_PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'output-audio')
os.makedirs(OUTPUT_AUDIO_FOLDER_PATH, exist_ok=True)

watermark_audio = AudioSegment.from_file('path/to/watermark.wav')

## Function to watermark the audio with the provided file path
def audio_watermarking(audio_files_paths: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    """
    A function to watermark the audio files given their paths.

    If the duration of the audio is 20 seconds or less, put one watermark in the middle.
    If the duration of the audio is more than 20 seconds, put a watermark every 15 seconds.
    """

    outputs_paths = []  # List to store the output paths
    for audio_file_path in audio_files_paths:
        try:
            # Load the main source audio file
            main_source_audio = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file_path)
            audio_duration = len(main_source_audio)  # Get the duration of the audio in milliseconds

            ## Calculate the scaling factor based on the amplitude of the main audio 
            ## (dBFS is often negative)
            scaling_factor = main_source_audio.dBFS / watermark_audio.dBFS

            ## Initialize the output audio as a copy of the main source audio
            output_audio = main_source_audio[:]

            if audio_duration <= 20000:  # Duration is 20 seconds or less
                ## Place a single watermark in the middle of the audio
                mid_point = audio_duration / 2
                output_audio = output_audio.overlay(watermark_audio - scaling_factor * 3, position=mid_point - len(watermark_audio) / 2)
            else:
                ## Duration is more than 20 seconds, place watermarks every 10 seconds
                interval_duration = 10 * 1000  # Interval for watermarking (10 seconds)
                position = interval_duration
                while position + len(watermark_audio) <= audio_duration:
                    # Overlay watermark at the specific position
                    output_audio = output_audio.overlay(watermark_audio - scaling_factor * 2, position=position - len(watermark_audio) / 2)
                    position += interval_duration

            # Export the watermarked audio
            output_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT_AUDIO_FOLDER_PATH, os.path.basename(audio_file_path))
            output_audio.export(output_path)

            # Append the output path to the list
            outputs_paths.append(output_path)
        
        except Exception as e:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f'There is an error in watermarking the file {audio_file_path} // {str(e)}')

    return outputs_paths
```

I tried many solutions like chuking the track and working concurrently on the same time and finally concatenate all of that, but my solution has duplicates and not that good

Comment: Where is most of the time spent? In `.from_file()`, in `.overlay()`, or in `.export()` ? [Profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) it, or use `t0 = time(); ... ; elapsed = time() - t0`

Comment: in ```overlay```

Answer (score 1):

[I'm going to assume that the "short", < 20 second, case goes quickly.]

Problem summary: Repeatedly doing `.overlay()` of four
`watermark.wav` segments per minute goes "slowly".

We do not yet have any timing measurements to quantify that.

## app

Let's look at the source.
For a ten-minute .wav file, we make forty of these calls:

```
                output_audio = output_audio.overlay(
                    watermark_audio - scaling_factor * 3,
                    position=mid_point - len(watermark_audio) / 2)
```

Now, there's something compiler folks call
[hoisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler#Loop_optimizations)
that we could do here.
We could compute the reduced volume
`watermark_audio - scaling_factor * 3`
just once before the loop starts,
since the scale factor won't change within the loop.
Worth doing, but it probably won't make much difference.

## library

https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/996cec42/pydub/audio_segment.py#L1175

In `.overlay()` I'm going to assume,
with no measurements,
that `AudioSegment._sync()` is "fast".

The next thing we do is assign `seg1 = seg1[position:]._data`,
which for a half-hour segment looks like an expensive slice,
a lot of data copying.
We do it repeatedly, with quadratic cost.

Action items:

1. OP probably wants to make measurements, to verify that's where we spend our time.
2. We might author improved code which patches `.overlay()` to make more efficient use of numpy when mixing signals together, so we don't copy a half hour of unchanged audio.
3. App could work around this by only feeding 15-second segments to `.overlay()`, and then worry about gluing the results together.